# How to pass env variable to a kubectl exec script call?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, environment-variables, exec

How do I pass a environment variable into a kubectl exec command, which is calling a script?

```
kubectl exec client -n namespace -- /mnt/script.sh
```

In my `script.sh`, I need the value of the passed variable.

I tried:

```
kubectl exec client -n namespace -- PASSWORD=pswd /mnt/script.sh
```

which errors with:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "PASSWORD=pswd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**env**(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env)

```bash
kubectl exec client -n namespace -- \
  env PASSWORD=pswd /mnt/script.sh
```

or explicitly wrap the command in an **sh**(1) invocation so a shell processes it

```bash
kubectl exec client -n namespace -- \
  sh -c 'PASSWORD=pswd /mnt/script.sh'
```

This comes with the usual caveats around `kubectl exec`: a "distroless" image may not have these standard tools; you're only modifying one replica of a Deployment; your changes will be lost as soon as the Pod is deleted, which can sometimes happen outside of your control.